Convert vertical data to horizontal and vice versa in PowerBI
I have a table like this in power bi:



Channel
Month
Regular Amount
Single Amount




A
January
123.1
111.1


B
January
345.3
222.2


B
February
678.6
333.3



I need to convert the Month as column and the column Regular Amount & Single Amount as row like this:



Channel
Type
January
February




A
Regular Amount
123.1
0


A
Single Amount
111.1
0


B
Regular Amount
345.3
678.6


B
Single Amount
222.2
333.3



Can someone assist?

These transformation should be done in Power Query with the following steps:

Unpivot the Regular Amount and Single Amount columns
Rename columns
Pivot the Month column
Replace null values with 0

let
    // Load your data source here
    Source = ... ,
    
    // Unpivot Regular Amount and Single Amount columns
    Unpivoted = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Channel", "Month"}, "Type", "Value"),
    
    // Pivot the Month column
    Pivoted = Table.Pivot(Unpivoted, List.Distinct(Unpivoted[Month]), "Month", "Value", List.Sum),
    
    // Replace nulls with 0
    ReplacedNulls = Table.ReplaceValue(Pivoted, null, 0, Replacer.ReplaceValue, List.Skip(Table.ColumnNames(Pivoted), 2)) // Skipping Channel and Type columns
in
    ReplacedNulls


